# Prototype - function inside each() - only returns the last value

Tags: function, prototypejs, each

I'm trying to load the image from each thumbnail and add an Opentip (opentip.org).

I've been successful in adding the  tag and creating the tooltip. The only problem is that only the last value in the array is displayed - for every thumbnail.

Here's a link to one product: http://www.inusual.com.br/poltrona-evo.html

The original HTML is

> ```
>     <div class="ca-thumbnails">
>     <div>
>         <img src="xxx">
>     </div>
>     <div>
>         <img src="xxx">
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

I've added the  randomly. Everything works fine and is added correctly to each img. Only the image is not showing ok.

```
var tip = $$('.ca-thumbnails div img');
tip.each(function(s, index) {

   src = s.readAttribute('src');
   function image() {

    return Builder.node('img', { 'src': src });
   }

    s.wrap('a', { 'class': 'tip', 'onclick':'return false;', 'href': src});
    s.up(0).addTip(image, { ajax: false, showEffect: 'appear', showon:'mouseover', className:'glass', containInViewport: true, target: true, stem: true, tipJoint: [ 'center', 'bottom' ], targetJoint: [ 'center', 'top' ] });
```

I believe the function image() gets only the last item.

Does anyone has a clue on this?
Sorry about my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `image` function is not getting called when you're expecting. I'm not 100% sure why it's not erroring, but instead of passing in an element to addTip, you're passing in a reference to a function (`image`). Try this to see if it fixes the issue:

```
var tip = $$('.ca-thumbnails div img');
tip.each(function(s, index) {

    var src = s.readAttribute('src');
    var image = new Element('img', {src: src});

    s.wrap('a', { 'class': 'tip', 'onclick':'return false;', 'href': src});
    s.up(0).addTip(image, { ajax: false, showEffect: 'appear',  showon:'mouseover', className:'glass', containInViewport: true, target: true, stem: true,   tipJoint: [ 'center', 'bottom' ], targetJoint: [ 'center', 'top' ] });
});
```

Don't forget to use the `var` keyword! I see you have a global `image` variable, which may (or may not) have something to do with why these particular lines of code aren't erroring and giving you a clue on what's wrong.